# How to elegantly slice the object

Tags: c++, object-slicing

So basically I have a class `SomethingSwimming` and a derived class `Ship`. I want to implement that upon some event a `Ship` may lose its special qualities (such as holding lobsters hostage) and become just another `SomethingSwimming` object.

To illustrate:

```
class SomethingSwimming
{
    protected:
    int m_treasures;

    public:
    SomethingSwimming(int treasures): m_treasures(treasures) {;}
    virtual int howManyLobstersOnBoard() {return 0; }
};

class Ship: public SomethingSwimming
{
    protected:
    int m_lobstersOnBoard;

 public:
    Ship(int treasures, int lobstersOnBoard): SomethingSwimming(treasures), m_lobstersOnBoard(lobstersOnBoard) {;}
    int howManyLobstersOnBoard() {return m_lobstersOnBoard; }
};

void crash(shared_ptr<SomethingSwimming>& b)
{
    b = make_shared<SomethingSwimming>(100);
}

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<SomethingSwimming> a = make_shared<Ship>(100, 12);

    cout << "How many lobsters on board: " << a->howManyLobstersOnBoard() << endl;

    crash(a);

    cout << "How many lobsters on board: " << a->howManyLobstersOnBoard() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My question is how to `crash` the `Ship` so it becomes only `SomethingSwimming` (so it's not a `Ship` anymore) without reinitializing.

Comment: `Ship` already is `SomethingSwimming` because of inheritance

Comment: You can't really do it without creating a new object, like you do now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of cutting away rest of the object while keeping the identity of the base sub object. You can make a new copy of the base sub object, and throw away the derived object.

Currently you create an unrelated object in `crash` and thereby `m_treasures` won't be affected by `m_treasures` of the previously pointed object. To create a copy of the original base sub object, you can do:

```
b = make_shared<SomethingSwimming>(*b);
```

---

Alternatively, at the call site you can treat an indirectly referred base as if it were not part of a derived object by calling virtual member functions statically:

```
a->SomethingSwimming::howManyLobstersOnBoard()
```

This will result in the value of `m_treasures` regardless of the most derived type of the object.